# Bootstrap Carousel showing next and previous image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Is the bootstrap carousel extendible to show the next and previous images in the slider?

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/bike.png" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/bike2.png" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

My carousel looks like this at the moment, how can i add in the previous and next images to the currently active slide?

Comment: Unless you're absolutely locked into using only Bootstrap, Mike Alsup's Cycle plugin might be easier for this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5.3 (update 2023)**

With JS and CSS the "reveal" carousel can be acheived the same way in Bootstrap 5.3:

https://codeply.com/p/f6zckgIuE6

**Bootstrap 5.0 (update 2021)**

jQuery is no longer required for Bootstrap 5 so the cloning of the slides (needed for partial reveal of prev and next slide) can be done using vanilla JS.

```
slides.forEach((el) => {
    // number of slides per carousel-item
    const minPerSlide = slides.length
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = slides[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})
```

[Bootstrap 5 partial reveal carousel demo](https://codeply.com/p/jCzaESNi07)

---

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2019)**

Another variation is only reveal a portion of the next and previous slides. This can be done by placing an absolute position overlay over the left and right side of the `carousel-inner`..

```
.carousel-inner:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 82%;
    left: 0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.carousel-inner:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 82%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 partial carousel](https://codeply.com/go/QGkUVSqil8)
[Bootstrap 4 partial carousel (alternate)](https://codeply.com/p/Uu7BAsucey)

---

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

It is possible with Bootstrap, but requires some customizations...

See this example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/94444

You have to customize the position of the slides using CSS and jQuery..

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
```

Answer (score 18):

[image: screenshot]

### The solution for Bootstrap 4

Captions are visible on screens 768px wide or more.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/daLzpL

```js
$('.carousel-item', '.multi-item-carousel').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (! next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
}).each(function(){
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (! prev.length) {
    prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
  }
  prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this));
});
```

```css
.multi-item-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-indicators {
  margin-right: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control-prev,
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-control-next {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 11; /* .carousel-caption has z-index 10 */
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner {
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left),
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-right.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right),
.multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-left.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.multi-item-carousel .item__third {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user667430 this answer should be now the accepted answer. Thank you Gleb user6263942 
Its code base, approach and example are the most up-to-date to modern standards and totally supported in BootStrap 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that Bootstrap 3.3.5 is not supports the given solution unfortunately, there I made a completely new Bootstrap 3 carousel extension to reach the goal. It can be found at https://github.com/assarte/visor-carousel

Hope this could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) and copy the base code available and then tweak it according to your personal preferences.

Comment: Instead of responding with "read the documentation" type of answers, **try to answer the question with examples and your own explanation**. By clicking the edit button, you can modify your comment and include the necessary samples and instructions. **Instead of relying on external references, try to formulate the complete answer within your comment.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34511675)

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

### The solution for Bootstrap 5

Parts of adjacent slides are visible on screens 500px wide or more.
Captions are visible on screens 768px wide or more.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/BaEBogL

```js
$('.carousel-item', '.multi-item-carousel').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
}).each(function() {
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (!prev.length) {
    prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
  }
  prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this));
});
```

```css
.multi-item-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* hide clones of neighboring slides on mobile */
.multi-item-carousel .item__third:first-child,
.multi-item-carousel .item__third:last-child {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-indicators {
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-control-prev,
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-control-next {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 11; /* .carousel-caption has z-index 10 */
  }
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
  }
  
  /* slides receive these classes only while moving */
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-start),
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-end.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
  }
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end),
  .multi-item-carousel .carousel-item-start.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  }
  
  /* now the content of the current slide occupies only a third of it between the clones of two adjacent slides */
  .multi-item-carousel .item__third {
    display: block !important;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    /* captions can now be added */
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="item__third">
          <img src="https://place-hold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```