# How to display previous and next images with a Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The effect I'm looking for can be seen in the following image, it is a carousel with 3 images.

How can I make the bootstrap carousel show the left and right images with an opacity of 0.7?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufna9.jpg]

The following is my carousel template.

```html
<div class="col-md-10 center-block">
    <img id="logo" src="./img/yoox_group.png" alt="yoog group" />

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./img/carousel/carousel-001.jpg" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/carousel/carousel-002.jpg" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/carousel/carousel-003.jpg" alt="..." />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <img id="arrowleft" src="./img/arrow_left.png" />
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <img id="arrowright" src="./img/arrow_right.png" />
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#arrowleft {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -95px;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
#arrowright {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 67px;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349746/4639281) to another question, if you add the following css to your code it will provide the effect you're looking for.

We basically have to expand `.carousel-inner` to be larger than `.carousel`, then center it and hide the overflow of `.carousel`.

To obtain the opacity effect, we expand the size of the previous and next arrow containers, then set a translucent white background.

---

**Bootstrap >= 3.3.0**

In Bootstrap version 3.3.0 [there was a change in the CSS which invalidated the previous method](https://www.diffchecker.com/i0mzc7sd). So this is the current method.

([Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/jadahetoxi))

```css
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
}
```

---

**Bootstrap < 3.3.0**

([Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/cipucewiya))

```css
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -33%;
}
.carousel-inner .next {
    left: 33%;
}
.carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -33%;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just tried it on firefox and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm busy at work right now, I'll take a better look at it when I get some time later on.

Comment: @gsamaras old answer, will check it out and update it tonight

Comment: That is a clever solution! I needed to enlarge the middle slide and that is easily done by editing the percentage values in .carousel-inner { width: 150%; left: -25%; }