# Showing previews (previous and next image) with bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue showing previews of the previous and next images/slides with bootstrap carousel. I have followed the instructions in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569225/how-to-display-previous-and-next-images-with-a-bootstrap-carousel) StackExchange article, but no matter how many times I start again and re-write it, it just wont show properly.

It keeps getting truncated and showing below.

I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxu3b2f3/1/) to demonstrate the issue.

I don't want to show much of the next slides, maybe 20px worth either side, mostly just to prompt the user to slide/swipe.

```
    .carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 25%;
}
```

Any help on where I have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Anton

Comment: Your fiddle example is far from the original SO question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. While there are some differences between the original SO question, I am not sure that they are far from similar. Granted the original question is slightly different, the end solution I am looking to achieve is very similar. The answer in both cases would be a bootstrap carousel that centers the current item, and shows a partial preview of the next and previous images at either side. This is exactly the effect I am aiming to re-produce.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to reinvent the wheel and to choose a slider which already has the functionality you are looking for or at leas something similar.

In my opinion [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is one of the best sliders and it comes with a huge amount of customisation possibilities. In your case I would have a closer look the **Center Mode** of [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

All you have to do to achieve your goal is change the styling and the `slidesToShow` property.