# Carousel CSS works in IE 11 but nothing else, different CSS works in everything but IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, carousel

The carousel has an image preview for next and previous images. Selecting previous or next should cause a smooth transition to previewed image.

This CSS works in Chrome 58, Firefox 53, and Edge 40, but totally messes up in IE 11.

```
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {

        -webkit-transform: translateX(33%);
        transform: translateX(33%);
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {

        -webkit-transform: translateX(-33%);
        transform: translateX(-33%);        
    }
}
```

Code largely from: [How to display previous and next images with a Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569225/how-to-display-previous-and-next-images-with-a-bootstrap-carousel/31570790#31570790)

I found that the following works in IE11, but badly messes up in anything else tested.

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .active.right{ left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }


.carousel-inner:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    left: 0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
.carousel-inner:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Code largely from: [Bootstrap Carousel showing next and previous image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346847/bootstrap-carousel-showing-next-and-previous-image/20349746#20349746)

Is there is a way to either combine the two styles into a single piece that works for every browser, or, if there is a (sensible) way to do browser detection and serve only that CSS, I am open to it. From my understanding, parsing a User Agent string is not ideal, and neither is using 'CSS Hacks' to distinguish browsers.

http://jsbin.com/rifoqecaku/edit?css,output
The IE CSS is commented.

Note: The reason '{' is on a new line is that it contains code edited by me from it's source. Otherwise, it should be accurate to the original. That was done to help me read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the CSS to wrap the IE section with

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active)
```

in addition to adding the following to the IE CSS

```
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {

    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {

    -webkit-transform: translateX(-0%);
    transform: translateX(-0%);

}
```

and **also moving the IE CSS below everything else's CSS** appears to have fixed the issue sufficiently for my purposes. What still remains is handling the IE transition when the screen size it too small. In everything else, it removes the left and right window, leaving just the middle window, and continues to act normally. In IE, it removes those windows, but the transition starts about half of the way through, though with only a quick glance, it doesn't appear to be consistent. I am not going to worry myself over that one detail.

This appears to only affect IE's transition. I have tested in several desktop browsers at reduced width, as well as Firefox, Chrome, and Samsung Internet on Android.

Simply using the media query is insufficient, you must remove the translateX().