# How to make a ''ChromeStore-style" slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question that how to write the structure of this slideshow - only showing part of the objects at the left and right side.

THanks in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346847/bootstrap-carousel-showing-next-and-previous-image) has already made the carousel with peeking images. Here's the codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/QGkUVSqil8