# How to create bootstrap carousel with near by Next/Previous images?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I have created bootstrap carousel. it's working fine but how can i show next and previous images on next and previous buttons.

below in the url you can see what i have done till now.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjddP.jpg

```
<div class="container image-slides">
    <div class="row r">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/festival-slider.jpg"
                    alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/festival-slider.jpg"
                    alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/festival-slider.jpg"
                    alt="Third slide">
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>              

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

I want to show next and previous nearby images in arrow buttons.now i just have changes arrow to static images.

Comment: Just to check if I understand you :are you saying that you want different images to appear when you click your arrow buttons?

Comment: yes different nearby images.

Comment: this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346847/bootstrap-carousel-showing-next-and-previous-image

Comment: it is not what i am looking for