# How to make slider like this

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

[Slider template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jMGR.png)

I`m using a slick-slider and tried to make this with CenterMode but I don't know how to make other pictures look like this.
Should I use pseudo-elements or what?

Comment: This is what you're looking for:  [SO Carousel Slider] - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346847/bootstrap-carousel-showing-next-and-previous-image

Comment: Please put the code you have so far into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the individual slide HTML you can add an element, and style that element to be absolute, and cover the full slide.

Then you want to give the overlay in the active slide an opacity of 0, to highlight the current slide (hide the overlay for the current slide). SlickJs gives the current slide the class "slick-current" (without quotes). You can then do something like:

```
/* Make sure the overlay will be placed inside the box */
.your-slider .slick-slide {
   position: relative;
}

.your-slider .slick-slide .overlay {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.your-slider .slick-slide.slick-current .overlay {
   opacity: 0;
}
```