# Would be possible to recreate this carousel with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'd like to re-create this carousel with Bootstrap 5, so far I have the navigation alike but can't figure out how to display the items side by side.

[image]

On this example, clicking the item place it on center but it seems to break sometimes.

**My jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/dianakc/acznyd2j/7/

```css
#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-indicators {
  column-gap:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:initial;
}
#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-indicators button {
  border:none;
  padding:8px 20px;
  border-radius:25px;
  margin:auto;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px 18px;;
    margin:0;
    text-indent: initial;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border:none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color:#87B6C8;color:#fff;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators {width:600px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">

  <div class="carousel-indicators mt-2 mb-2">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">Slide 1</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">Slide 2</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"> Slide 3</button>
  </div>


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/16/2500/1667" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/4928/3264" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/55/4608/3072" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Carousel showing next and previous image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346847/bootstrap-carousel-showing-next-and-previous-image)